# Angular: Using [FormControl] in input

Tags: forms, angular

(Angular 4): What is the difference between

```
<input type="text"
id="productNameInput"
[formControl]="myForm.get('productName')"
[(ngModel)]="productName
```

and

```
<input type="text"
id="productNameInput"
[formControl]="myForm.controls['productName']"
[(ngModel)]="productName
```

Are the two ways of assigning to formControl effectively the same? When would you use each?

Thanks

Comment: Read [the docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) (links through to [`AbstractControl.get`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get)) - `.get` can take a *path*, which would potentially be much neater if you had nested form groups.

Comment: can't fully confirm, but according to [this](https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter#aot--donts), the usage of `AbstractControl.get()` is favored over the other for AOT compilation.

Comment: Hey Jesse! I'm a bit confused by your example. Using `ngModel` and two-way binding is for template-driven forms. Using `formControl` is for reactive forms? And is not normally used if you have a form group such as `myForm` defined. Then `formControlName` is most often used.